# Mongoose relationship rendering with json

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two models.

Like:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let Like = new Schema({
    value: {
        type: Number
    }
}, { timestamps: true })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Like', Like)
```

AND

Report:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let Report = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    summary: {
        type: String
    },
    analysis: {
        type: String
    },
    source_title: {
        type: String
    },
    source_link: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {
        type: String
    },
    like: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Like'
    },
    player: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Player'
    }
}, { timestamps: true })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Report', Report)
```

I have two goals:

1. I want to be able to track every like and associate them with them with a report.
2. I want to be able to render report as json in this route.

```
const express = require('express')
const reportRoutes = express.Router()
let Report = require('../models/Report')


reportRoutes.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    try {

       const report = await Report.find()
        .populate({path: 'like'})
        .populate({
             path    : 'player',
             populate: [
                 { path: 'team' }
             ]
        })

        res.json(report)

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})

reportRoutes.route('/:id').get(async (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id
    Report.findById(id, function(err, report){
        res.json(report)
    })
})

reportRoutes.route('/add').post(function(req, res){
    let report = new Report(req.body)
    report.save()
        .then(report => {
            res.status(200).json({'report': 'report added successfully!'})
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding new report failed :(')
        })
})

reportRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function(req, res){
    Report.findById(req.params.id, function(err, report) {
        if (!report)
            res.status(404).send('data is not found')
        else
            report.title = req.body.title
            report.desc = req.body.desc
            report.markdown = req.body.markdown

            report.save().then(report => {
                res.json('Report updated!!!')
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send('Update didnt work')
            })
    })
})

module.exports = reportRoutes
```

The way that this is currently configured works, HOWEVER, I feel like there is a certain limitation.

Each time I create a like for a report, I will have to also update report to add the id for the specific like.

I'm guessing there's a much better way to do this. My background is in Rails and Posgresql, so Mongo/Mongoose is throwing me off a little bit.

Comment: May I ask, why you chose to create a new collection for the likes instead of making them a direct property of Report? So something like this:    { like: Number }. (if you only define the .type field in a Schema Property, you can also leave it out and directly enter the type.

Comment: I want to have it’s own collection to be able to track likes for specific users; this way I can track if that sow specific user has liked that specific card before. Can you expand on your second sentence?